# visual studio 2015 warning: Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, dependencies

I made c# project using visual studio 2012 Then i want to open this project again using visual studio 2015 but i received this error message

[image: Error message]

After searching for any solution, i founded that the solution is Editting the `GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution` section in the .snl file.
But when i open my .snl file, i can not find this section.
This is my **.snl file**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00   
Visual Studio 14   
VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.23107.0   
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1   
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Testpro",            
"Testpro\Testpro.csproj", "{CA0D0730-0B11-40B3-9604-458CA6272CA9}"   
EndProject   
Global   
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution    
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    Debug|Default = Debug|Default
    Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
    {CA0D0730-0B11-40B3-9604-458CA6272CA9}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg =    
Debug|Any CPU   
    {CA0D0730-0B11-40B3-9604-458CA6272CA9}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any     
CPU   
    {CA0D0730-0B11-40B3-9604-458CA6272CA9}.Debug|Default.ActiveCfg =    
Debug|Any CPU   
    {CA0D0730-0B11-40B3-9604-458CA6272CA9}.Debug|Default.Build.0 = Debug|Any    
CPU   
    {CA0D0730-0B11-40B3-9604-458CA6272CA9}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any    
CPU   
EndGlobalSection   
GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution    
    HideSolutionNode = FALSE   
EndGlobalSection   
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution   
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU   
    Debug|Default = Debug|Default   
    Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU   
    Release|Default = Release|Default   
EndGlobalSection   
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution   
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU   
    Debug|x64 = Debug|x64   
    Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU   
    Release|x64 = Release|x64   
EndGlobalSection   
EndGlobal
```

I tried this solution:
changing the Solution Platform to Default Then remove all other Solution Platform from .snl file but it did not work.

Any help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Was the solution file created with an older version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, my project is created using VS2012

Comment: In the Visual Studio "Output" window, there should be additional details (you don't see in your screen shot). That should give us more details as to what is wrong. Likely the issue is related to a change Microsoft made to the solution file layout in VS2015.

Comment: no more details are shown ! Just this warning (
Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read.)